# Eclipse - Connecting to SQL Server 2014 Using JDBC

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, odbc, sql-server-2014-express

I have and Enterprise Java Bean project. I'm attempting to use a web client to access a Java Application Server to go and grab information from a database. So far I've only reached the point where I should try to connect to the database with Java using the Eclipse Java EE IDE.

In the database development view I'm attempting to make the database connection. The only templates available are MS SQL 2000, 2005, & 2008. I can't seem to find a way to add 2014 as a type. The Eclipse documentation for this, found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fasc1229700372057.html) only describes a process that again leads to a list that doesn't go higher than 2008.

I have already downloaded the Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server and have tried pointing the 2008 template to the sqljdbc4 jar, to no avail. I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
```

I attempted a manual login, and that did not work either. The connection should be valid, when connecting through the ODCB Data Source Administrator in Windows 7 the connection goes through easily.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971856/jdbc-connection-from-eclipse-to-mssql-server-using-sqljdbc4-jar) answer to include the jar directly in the package so I can just code the connection, but I am not sure where to put it since I don't have a WEB-INF folder.

I also found [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1042394/) answer, but it doesn't make much sense, other than to just apply the 2014 driver to the 2008 template, which I tried.

Comment: re: "This driver is not configured for integrated authentication" - I assume that you've added the JAR file for the SQL Server JDBC driver to the "Libraries" tab of the Build Path for the Eclipse project. If so, have you tried setting the "Native library location" option to the folder containing the "sqljdbc_auth.dll" file, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mM6zX.png)?

Comment: I just added that about a half hour ago and made progress. I got an error about a mini-dump, found a solution which was to delete my metadata folder and restart eclipse. That broke my project; it must have deleted some of the java stuff necessary to run the program.

Comment: You need to have the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` on the `java.library.path` (or on the system path). See the linked duplicate and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated

Comment: You are right, and I added that already. There was an additional problem with the wrong version of another jar file, I will write about that later.